# MySQL How can I get data where certain column value is undefined?

Tags: mysql, select, undefined

I was thinking I could do that like `SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name=UNDEFINED`, but I couldn't. I think there is a simple way to do that?

Comment: Not UNDEFINED.  Try `NULL`

Comment: This is really, really basic. Maybe some more detail would be great?

Comment: thanks. I will use NULL.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what you think is UNDEFINED.

The most basic case is that your column_name is nullable, so your query would look like:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

In mysql you compare to NULL values with something like:

```
SELECT * from table_name where column_name IS NULL
```